# Data analyzing a csv file into list, not getting the same result as my teacher

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am a beginner to python.

I am working on an assignment where I have to

1. import pandas library
2. read a csv file
3. analyze dataframe by making them into a list
4. use loops to find specific word in each row of list

When I try to pull certain values from the list according to the word "New York" it is pulling numbers that do not have the word "New York" in the row.

I have attached my code and my teachers code as an example. I am trying to get my output to look like my teachers. Please let me know if you need anything else. Thank you!

[my code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeAQH.png)

[my teachers code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rps3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a tab in print ('Order Amount: $'). so the order amount and running total are not filtered. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy1yA.png)

Comment: You should post codes samples as text formatted as code